# flutter change State name

Tags: flutter, dart

In the following code, I want to change "HomePage" to "todoScreen" in every area that is relevant. How can I do that beside  ctr+F?

```
class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homepage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  // create a database object so ew can access db functions
  var db = DatabaseConnect();
```

Comment: ctrl+F is the way to do it... but you can also create a new stateful widget and transfer later on the contents, just type stf and type the new name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renaming is a common operation related to refactoring source code and VS Code has a separate Rename Symbol command (F2). Some languages support rename symbol across files. Press F2 and then type the new desired name and press Enter. All usages of the symbol will be renamed, across files.

Example : For Macbook , click on the class name you will find this option then change the updated name .

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can search HomePage class in files (there is a search icon under explorer in the left side) and replace all of them by todoScreen.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidStudio (or IntelliJ for that matter):

1. right-click the class Name in Question
2. go to Refactor -> Rename..
3. a window will ask you for the new name
4. enter new name
5. click 'Refactor'

Android Studio will then rename all references in the project accordingly, so if you rename the Stateful *HomePage* to *MyPage* it will also cleverly rename *_HomePageState* to _*MyPageState*.

Instead of using the menu, you can just  , btw.